# Simple MySQL query tuning for 1 million records

Tags: mysql

I am just trying run simple query in db table which has almost 1 million records.  The problem is  it is  taking hours of time to execute simple query.  Please check the  query below.

```
Select * from users where (status='active' or status='pending') and 
usertype='buyer'
```

I have tried to create indexes for columns status and usertype with all possible ways but I didn't see any result.

I am using InnoDB database.   I just want some tuning techniques where I can get results in fraction of seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: how many records you want to be displayed

Comment: How many rows does this return? What index did you try (one on usertype, status should help)? Can you show a query plan?

Comment: Even with no indexes, a simple query like this on a single table with 1 million rows should not take "hours".  Are you exaggerating?  Or is it possible that `users` is really a view or has very long text/blob columns?

Comment: @rohitr I am just trying to get all records to  import Apache solr.

Comment: @Thilo I have tried all possbile ways.On each of single column and combination of both columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is simple table not view and  no long text/blog coloumns.  I don't understand mean by exaggerating.

Answer (score 0):

Create `Index`.

More information here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

and here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

I prefer btree (or custom type) index with constraint.

Comment: Can I know exactly how btree index will be used for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

First, write the query like this:

```
Select *
from users
where status in ('active', 'pending') and usertype = 'buyer';
```

`in` is just much easier to read than a bunch of `or`s.

Next, create the following index:

```
create index users_usertype_status on users(usertype, status);
```

Comment: I have done as you suggested but I found no difference .

Comment: @user3264996 . . . Replace the `select *` with `select count(*)`.  If this runs fast, then the likely culprit is your connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ....

You have three levels of tuning.

Physical tuning:
    Buy more Disks.

Physical layer tuning:
         Create Index like 
    create index idx_users_status on users(status);
    create index idx_users_usertype on users(user type);

And you can all so work with views as sub result.

```
create v_buyers as Select * from users where usertype='buyer';
select * from v_buyers where status in ('active', 'pending');
```

This can provide a tuning effect on multi core machines.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I am using AWS db.m3.large RDS instance. As you might be known it is good configuration.
I have already created indexes all possible ways but no luck.
I don't believe views work for me as it takes hours of time to create/update the view.
Also following query also taking hours of time to execute.
Select * from users where status in ('active', 'pending');

Answer (score 0):

Ok if your data are time scope you can use RANGE-Partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id INT NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(30),
lname VARCHAR(30),
hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
job_code INT NOT NULL,
store_id INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (store_id) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (21)
);
```

Or List - Partitioning over "buyer"

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id INT NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(30),
lname VARCHAR(30),
hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
job_code INT,
store_id INT
)
PARTITION BY LIST(store_id) (
PARTITION pNorth VALUES IN (3,5,6,9,17),
PARTITION pEast VALUES IN (1,2,10,11,19,20),
PARTITION pWest VALUES IN (4,12,13,14,18),
PARTITION pCentral VALUES IN (7,8,15,16)
);
```